# About group theory..

Tags: group-theory

Now we all know that if G is a group, there are some conditions applied such:

1. Associative binary operation.
2. Identity element.
3. Every element has its inverse.

For example : $G=U(10)=\{1,3,7,9\}$ is a group because $G$ will be :
$$\begin{matrix}
1& 3& 7& 9 \\
3& 9& 1& 7 \\
7& 1& 9& 3 \\
9& 7& 3& 1 
\end{matrix}$$
Now, all conditions have been achieved.
Now, my problem is: How i can execute the process by conversely? in other words, if i have set of numbers as $\{1\ 3\ 7\ 9\ 3\ 9\ 1\ 7\ 7\ 1\ 9\ 3\ 9\ 7\ 3\ 1\}$ how i can detect that operation (or that function) which will be responsible for generating of that set of numbers to be a Valid Group? (which is Multiplication mod 10). Therefor, i will be able to detect the main elements of the group (1 3 7 9) and the identity element and the inverse of every element .
Is there any way, any science, any department of math. discusses this problem or solves it?
Note that: I Wouldn't like depend on observation, I just need to depend on the math's law, I mean, if you put the numbers $$\begin{matrix}
1& 3& 7& 9 \\
3& 9& 1& 7 \\
7& 1& 9& 3 \\
9& 7& 3& 1 
\end{matrix}$$
 in front of your eyes you may observe symmetry and you will start in solve it on the grounds that it is a Group.

Thank you very much ,

I'm very sorry for confusing you, but I'll ask the question again..

Consider that you observed some particle that moves in space and forms specific pattern during it moves. We will assume that particle moves on straight line and we have equally divided it to 9 points, then you observed that particle just goes to 4 specific points (1,3,7,9) by forming this pattern (1,3,7,9,3,9,1,7,7,1,9,3,9,7,3,1).

I have just numbers and I don't know these numbers will form group or not. Basically I don't know any thing about the operation which will be responsible for forming the group.Now my question again is :

What can i do to conclude that mathematical operation which is responsible for generating and forming this set of numbers ?

After detecting the operation ,then I'll be able to test that set is a group or not by applying the 4 conditions, then I'll be able to determine the kind of this group then I'll detect that group is U(10) under multiplication mod 10.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. There is one more property that you did not mention: Closure.

Comment: Associative binary operation

Comment: Does not guarantee the result will be within the set.

Comment: @user3735754 Binary operation just means to assign every pair of elements of the set exactly one element, but not necessarily belonging to the set from which the pair were situated.

Comment: @user3735754 I have answered your question, please take a look and tell me if there is something un-clear and I will try to explain further.

Comment: @BLAZE , thank you for your effort ,but this answer is not for my question , i'll edit my question and i'll make it more clear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm going to show you how to prove that a set $S$ forms a group $G$ **without** using an operation table for a finite set, which is what I believe you were asking. So if given $\{1\ 3\ 7\ 9\ 3\ 9\ 1\ 7\ 7\ 1\ 9\ 3\ 9\ 7\ 3\ 1\}$ and you want to prove whether or not the set forms a group, you need to prove that each of the `four` fundamental group properties are satisfied for elements $a,b,c \in S$.

$\color{blue}{1.}$ **Associativity**: $a\cdot (b \cdot c)=(a\cdot b) \cdot c \space\space\space\forall \space a,b,c \in S$

$\color{green}{2.}$ **Identity**: $a \cdot e=e \cdot a=a \space\space\space\forall \space a  \in S$, where $e$ is the Identity element

$\color{red}{3.}$ **Inverse**: $\forall \space a\in S$ $ \exists \space b  \in S$: $a \cdot b=b \cdot a=e$

$\color{purple}{4.}$ **Closure**: If $a,b\in S$ then $a \cdot b \in S \space\space\space \forall \space a,b \in S$

Starting with $\color{blue}{1.}$

$$a\cdot (b \cdot c)=1\cdot (3 \cdot 7)=1\cdot 1=1$$
$$(a\cdot b) \cdot c= (1\cdot 3) \cdot 7=3 \cdot 7=1$$ So Associativity holds.

Please note although not shown here; to justify this rigorously you would have to repeat this for *every* trio $a\cdot (b \cdot c)=(a\cdot b) \cdot c$.

Now for $\color{green}{2.}$

$$a \cdot e=e$$
$$1\cdot 1=1$$ 
$$1\cdot 3 = 3$$
$$1\cdot 7 = 7$$
$$1\cdot 9 = 9$$

So the Identity element is $1$.

For $\color{red}{3.}$

$$a \cdot b=b \cdot a=e$$
$$1 \cdot 1=1=e$$
$$3 \cdot 7=1=e$$
$$7 \cdot 3=1=e$$
$$9 \cdot 9=1=e$$
So $3$ and $7$ are inverses of each other and $9$ is self-inversive and so is $1$, but that's obvious as $e\cdot e=e=1$.

Lastly for $\color{purple}{4.}$

We observe that $1,3,7,9 \in G$

So closure is satisfied.

---

Hence, you would now conclude that the set $\{1\ 3\ 7\ 9\ 3\ 9\ 1\ 7\ 7\ 1\ 9\ 3\ 9\ 7\ 3\ 1\}$ forms a group under multiplication mod $10$.

---

You already have the binary operation it was given to you at the start, the binary operation is multiplication mod $10$. It's binary because it takes $2$ elements and performs an operation on them and will give only **one** answer.

For example, multiplication mod $10$ means find the remainder when $a \times b$ is divided by $10$. This can be only one answer: An example is $3 \times 9= 27$ the remainder of this is $7$ when you divide it by $10$. In operator notation this is written $3 \cdot 7=7$.

So the only answer is $7$, that's why it is a 
`binary operation` as there are no more answers other than $7$. The $\cdot$ represents the binary operation. Any better?

Comment: please try to review my question after modification

Comment: @user3735754 I have read your edit, and I still believe that my answer is correct.

Comment: Based on which operation you applied the Associativity & Inverse ?

Comment: How did you conclude that the set forms a group under multiplication mod 10 ? Based on what ?

Comment: please , explain to me How did you conclude that the set forms a group under multiplication mod 10 ? Based on what ? and please don't tell me by observation

Comment: please don't tell me by observation. I know that you proved that the set is Group but any one can prove that while i talk about conclude the operation firstly then applying the 4 conditions on the set under the operation to make sure that the set with the operation create a Group

Comment: if you are interested in voting, no problem, i will . but for information you don't deserve this voting and ticking because you didn't answer my main question and you insists that ignore it .

Comment: these statements actually means that G is a Group

Comment: @user3735754 Yes you're right. So to prove a set forms a group you need to prove that the set is __closed__, the set has an __identity__, each element has an __inverse__ and the binary operation is __associative__. If all of this is true then the set is a group. That is exactly what I have done in my answer. Understand?

Comment: OK ..the binary operation is associative  but ...basically , what is the binary operation itself ? please ,don't tell me we will find it by observation

Comment: @user3735754 Please see the end of my answer, I have edited it for you as it was too big to fit in the comment.

Comment: @user3735754 Are you okay?

Answer (score 3):

It does not really work this way. Once you have a square table, like the one we have here, this **is** your operation. There is no point in asking which mathematical "reality" (like multiplication mod 10) is behind it; in fact, there is probably no "behind" at all. You could just as well have letters in place of numbers. You just check the group properties of this operation, and if they are all OK, here is your group.

Comment: Exactly. I was having a hard time understanding the question, with your answer I think I do. I think of them as permutations.

Comment: please try to review my question after modification

Answer (score 1):

I am still learning basic modern algebra but I am going to make a try.

1. Make two "outer product" tables and make sure they match.
2. Some one (and only one) whole Column & Row in the operation table gives the same as one of the factors. In your example this is row 1 & col 1.
3. The identity element exists once in each row and column in the operation table.

Also we need closure, that the result of operation stays within the set of group elements. This can be checked by comparing each element in the operation table with the set.

Comment: could you give to me an example ?

Comment: Say if you had 11 somewhere in your table, but 11 was not among the operands. Then the operation would not have closure.

Comment: please try to review my question after modification